# Linking table cells to network folders

Tags: wp-admin

Is it possible to create links to a network folder from within a table?

A colleague and myself have been struggling to link certain table cells to a network folder, for example: DB - Database would be linked to a network folder of the same name.

What we have tried:

1. Using `<a href="http://\\networkdrive\folder1\folder2\folder3\DB - Databases">DB - Databases</a>` returns a 'Sorry, the page was not found' error from our storage device
2. Using `<a href="file:///path/to/file.html">file</a> did not open the desired folder location` does not work or simply returns a 'About: blank' page
3. Using `<a href="file://///place.local/UserData/BNE/Projects" />some name link</a>` yielded the same results as mentioned above

The links I used for reference are: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-you-add-a-link-to-a-company-network-drive-on-a-page-using-file/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497169/how-to-create-a-link-in-wordpress-to-a-file-on-an-local-network-server

**Info about the network attached storage where the folder is stored:**

- It's a dedicated NAS device, specifically a Synology Rackstation RS2212RP+ running DSM 6.0
- The NAS hosts an array of disks and also provides three SMB shares (one of which I am trying to link to)

**Info about the WordPress machine:**

-Is a VM hosted within our ESXi environment

-Runs Debian 8 Jessie 64-bit

-LAMP and WordPress are installed as described [here](http://www.linuxserve.com/2015/05/install-latest-wordpress-version-on.html)

**Info about my test machine:**

-Runs Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

-WordPress pages are being made and edited in Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a mapped drive under windows:

```
<a href="file:///networkdrive/folder1/folder2/folder3/DB - Databases">DB - Databases</a>
```

If it is not a mapped dirve:

```
<a href="file://///server/folder1/folder2/folder3/DB - Databases">DB - Databases</a>
```

You should use the 3 `///` for the file protocol and 2 `//` for the network address.

More and more browsers seem to block links with the `file://` scheme on pages from `http://` and `https://` protocols. This used to work (years ago) on some browsers but Chrome and others don't accept them anymore. For a possible workaround see this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31547188/4021004

Your NAS should be able to make folders accessible via `http://` using WebDav, see the [Synology KB](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_with_WebDAV).

Comment: I have tried both options but they still give me a 'about:blank' page or are not clickable unless I open them in another tab which gives me said page.

Comment: @SP-Brown The please add more information about if or how the network drive is mounted, about used protocols (smb, nfs, etc.), OSes etc.

Comment: I have just added more information about the NAS, the WP host and my test machine. If you require more information, please let me know so I can provide.

Comment: @SP-Brown Linking from `http://` to `file://` seems to get blocked. I added some info for working around.